# Can i Access items that i set in Response Object through Request Object in express js?

Tags: javascript, express

I have this code

```
res.cookie("jid", token, {
httpOnly: false,
path: "/",
  });
console.log("cookee is : ",res.cookie.name);// cokkie name not accessible
console.log("cookee is : ",req.cookies); // here it is accessible
```

So i am surprised that i set cookiee in res object but i was not able to access it throuhg res object but i was able to access it throug req object.

Comment: `res.cookie()` is a function (as is clear from the fact you call it just above). I wouldn't expect to be able to find a name on it.

Comment: then how can i console cookie name using res object? because i set cookie in res object i want to retrieve it through same.

Answer (score 1):

You can find [the source code for `res.cookie()` here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/884e080a19015a81a46aef73792be12ad3220715/lib/response.js#L831-L860).

You can see that in the end, it calls [`this.append('Set-Header', ...)`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/884e080a19015a81a46aef73792be12ad3220715/lib/response.js#L721), which adds a header to the response.

The Express `response` [inherits](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/884e080a19015a81a46aef73792be12ad3220715/lib/response.js#L42) from [Node's `ServerResponse`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse), so the API to access the headers set on a response is [`res.getHeader()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_getheader_name).

So:

```
res.cookie("jid", ...);
console.log(res.getHeader('set-cookie'));
```

may do part of what you want here.

Comment: I still have one doubt --- how come cookie is available through request object because i set cookiee in response object  --- but immediately it is available in request object

Comment: The cookie in the request object is the one your browser sent to your server, even before you're setting a new one in the response you're sending.

Comment: I cleared cookie from browser before i sending new request still i am able to get it in request object

Comment: That's unrelated to this question and answer, isn't it?

Comment: i guess it's not completely unrelated, it's part of my question.